# Loading and using a PyTorch model from disk

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and on the very first page here -- https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html

The page expects me to run the whole code in the same file. That is, creating the model, training it, saving it to disk, loading it from disk and using the model for inference.

I see that the inference code relies on the model definition done during training. My question is, do I need to know the model definition to use a pre-trained model? That seems so wrong. I am sure it's not the case. Then, how do I use the saved model to do inference?

Googling showed me instances of importing the model using python's import function. However I couldn't find examples of how to load a model from disk and use it without knowing the definition of the model. Any help please?

I want to save the model loading and inference part of this code below to a different file and run it. I am not sure how to do that

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

# Download training data from open datasets.
training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
)

# Download test data from open datasets.
test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
)

batch_size = 64

# Create data loaders.
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=batch_size)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size)

for X, y in test_dataloader:
    print(f"Shape of X [N, C, H, W]: {X.shape}")
    print(f"Shape of y: {y.shape} {y.dtype}")
    break


# Get cpu, gpu or mps device for training.
device = (
    "cuda"
    if torch.cuda.is_available()
    else "mps"
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available()
    else "cpu"
)
print(f"Using {device} device")

# Define model
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28*28, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
print(model)# Get cpu, gpu or mps device for training.

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")



def test(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    model.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")



epochs = 5
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")

torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")
print("Saved PyTorch Model State to model.pth")


model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth"))

classes = [
    "T-shirt/top",
    "Trouser",
    "Pullover",
    "Dress",
    "Coat",
    "Sandal",
    "Shirt",
    "Sneaker",
    "Bag",
    "Ankle boot",
]

model.eval()
x, y = test_data[0][0], test_data[0][1]
with torch.no_grad():
    x = x.to(device)
    pred = model(x)
    predicted, actual = classes[pred[0].argmax(0)], classes[y]
    print(f'Predicted: "{predicted}", Actual: "{actual}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch models save the state dict of the model (`torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")`) which is just a dictionary of parameters. This is separate from the logic of the forward pass of the model, which is defined in your `nn.Module` class (`NeuralNetwork`).

The reason for doing this is saving the model class itself requires pickling the python object, which causes all sorts of headaches. The pytorch standard is to save just the parameters and create model class objects when needed.

To load a saved model, you first create a `NeuralNetwork` object, then load the saved state dict (`model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth"))`).